# Resize textarea in Meteor

Tags: jquery, meteor, meteorite

I'm trying to create an edit page, where the user can edit his content in a textarea resized to fit the content and I'm using this plugin to do that: http://www.jacklmoore.com/autosize/

But when I access the edit page the textarea doesn't resize to fit the content, this only happens if I refresh the page manually. Here is the code:

```
<template name="postEdit">
    <textarea autofocus name="content" type="text" value="">{{content}}</textarea>
</template>

Template.postEdit.rendered = function() {
     $('textarea').autosize(); 
};
```

I also tried with Meteor.defer, but it doesn't work:

```
Template.postEdit.rendered = function() {
    Meteor.defer(function() {
    $('textarea').autosize();
 });     
};
```

When I refresh the page manually and the textarea finally resizes, the textarea html changes for this:

```
<textarea class="review" name="review" type="text" value="" placeholder="Blablabla" style="overflow: hidden; word-wrap: break-word; resize: horizontal; height: 664px;"></textarea>
```

Is there any problem with my code or my approach is wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: If you enter `$('textarea').autosize();` in the console of your browser when the page is loaded and it doesn't work, the plugin is not loaded correctly.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, when I enter that in the console, it prints this <textarea type=​"text" value style class=​"review" name=​"review" placeholder=​"blablabla">​</textarea>​
, 
<textarea tabindex=​"-1" style=​"position:​ absolute;​ top:​ -999px;​ left:​ 0px;​ right:​ auto;​ bottom:​ auto;​ border:​ 0px;​ padding:​ 0px;​ box-sizing:​ content-box;​ word-wrap:​ break-word;​ overflow-x:​ hidden;​ -webkit-transition:​ none;​ transition:​ none;​ height:​ 0px !important;​ min-height:​ 0px !important;​ width:​ 564.65625px;​" class=​"autosizejs">​</textarea>​ , but the text area doesn't resize

Comment: When I refresh the page manually and the textarea finally resizes, the textarea html changes for this:

    <textarea class="review" name="review" type="text" value="" placeholder="Blablabla" style="overflow: hidden; word-wrap: break-word; resize: horizontal; height: 664px;"></textarea>

Comment: What happens if you do `$('.review').autosize();`

Comment: the problem might be that you trigger resize on both, the mirror element and your intended textarea. not sure tho..

Comment: When I enter $('.review').autosize(); nothing happens, the textarea only resizes when I refresh the page

Comment: The console only prints this: <textarea type=​"text" value style class=​"review" name=​"review" placeholder=​"Blablabla">​</textarea>​

Comment: It's normal that the console is printing the object you interact with. I tried with an example app and the plugin you used and it works with autosize().show().trigger(... , check my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As it states in the 'Known Issues & Solutions' [Docs of jQuery Autoresize](http://www.jacklmoore.com/autosize/) you might want to do:

```
Template.hello.rendered = function(){
    $('textarea').autosize().show().trigger('autosize.resize');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The actual problem is that the DOM is not fully loaded when you call the plugin.
This should work:

```
$(function(){
    $("textarea").autosize();
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried that inside Template.postEdit.rendered but it doesn't work

Comment: What if you try it in a script tag? Also ensure the plugin is actually loaded (i.e. check in the resources tab of developer tools)

Comment: Something like this? <script type="text/javascript"> $(function(){$("textarea").autosize();});</script> Which is the best place to put this script, on main.html? The plugin is loaded

Comment: Yes, that should be working. You can put it wherever you want, as long as it's in the client part

Comment: It doesn't work, not even when I refresh the page manually :/

Answer (score 0):

I'm no jQuery expert, but if I'm remembering correct, you can do this:

```js
Template.postEdit.rendered = function() {
     $(this.find('textarea')).autosize(); 
};
```

Answer (score -1):

Just try this way

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('textarea').autosize();   
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried that inside Template.postEdit.rendered but it doesn't work